# Dangling meta character + in regex to detect GaussianRational

Tags: java, regex

```
public GaussianRational read()  
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);     // associate Scanner object with standard input stream
    Long p,q,m,n; 
    s.findWithinHorizon("(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*(\\+? \\s* -?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+\\s*i)",0);// scan standard input for regular expression pattern

    MatchResult result = s.match();           // collect subtrings matched by "capturing groups" in the pattern (in parentheses)
    s.close();                                // scanner no longer needed
    p = Long.parseLong(result.group(1));     
    q = Long.parseLong(result.group(2));   
    m = Long.parseLong(result.group(3));     
    n = Long.parseLong(result.group(4));     
    System.out.print(p);
    return new GaussianRational(p,q,m,n);
}
```

I am trying to parse 4 long numbers from a `GaussianRational` input using regex below

```
(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+) \\s*(+?)\\s* (-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+\\s*i)
```

but I keep getting exception dangling `+` or  dangling `?` that are used in the middle of the expression

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you are using. I think the problem is not only with the regex (the only issue being an unescaped `+`). I am sure the issue is with parsing the groups. Try `"(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*(\\+?)\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*i"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add `.` before `+?`. Without dot `+` alone would be  meaningless since it's unescaped.

```
"(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*(.+?)\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*i"
```

If you actually mean a plus.

```
"(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*\\+?\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*i"
```

Comment: but this expression fails to capture any input 1/2+3/4 i, throws no match result available exception

Comment: @askatral check now.. if you actually mean a `+` then remove dot.

Comment: 1/2+3/4 i
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 i"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString

Comment: i mean to check + as is, removing the dot results in the same dangling + exception

Comment: @askatral did you notice that i escaped the `+`. still it shows error, then edit your question and post the code.

Comment: yes Avinash. It either gives dangling character exception or 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 i" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString

Comment: remove `\\s*i` from the capturing group.

Comment: it tries to convert `i` to long but it can't

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the plus symbol and move the last capturing group boundaries to the number:

```
Long p,q,m,n; 
s.findWithinHorizon("(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*(\\+?)\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*/\\s*(-?\\d+)\\s*i",0);
//                                                                                  ^
MatchResult result = s.match();           // collect subtrings matched by "capturing groups" in the pattern (in parentheses)
s.close();                                // scanner no longer needed
p = Long.parseLong(result.group(1));     
q = Long.parseLong(result.group(2));   
m = Long.parseLong(result.group(4));     
n = Long.parseLong(result.group(5));     
 // With "1/2+3/4 i" as input, the results are
System.out.println(p); // => 1
System.out.println(q); // => 2
System.out.println(m); // => 3
System.out.println(n); // => 4
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YKEla3)

Comment: 1/3+4/5iException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match result available 
is thrown

Comment: See [demo](http://ideone.com/qEPV0V), it works alright. The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Then why did you accept Avinash's answer? :) Please consider accepting my answer and upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)). I was the first to provide the CORRECT answer (I also asked for the real code and it was key to understanding your point).

Comment: @stribizhev i'm the one who first solves her issue of dangling meta char. Then she said that it shows number format exception, since because of urgent work, i get leaved. Then you come up and said her to change the capturing group. I don't know who the actual  answerer. It's just a small thing and you may post it as comment.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Ok, the problem with `+` was evident, it is child's play for either of us and I saw it right away. A less evident issue was with the capture group boundary. But I agree with you, there were 2 main issues here, and it is up to OP to make a choice which answer suits best. I asked because she wrote *it works Thanks lot!!!!* to me, not to you :)